# param.Integer assignment to python class transformed to int

Tags: python, python-3.8

```
import param

class BaseClass(param.Parameterized):
    num_int = param.Integer(50000, bounds=(-200, 100000))
```

Code block returns class int

```
>>> type(BaseClass.num_int)

'<class 'int'>'
```

instead of

```
>>> num_int = param.Integer(50000, bounds=(-200, 100000))
>>> type(num_int)

'<class 'param.Integer'>'
```

Is this intended behaviour or am I missing something?

Comment: Try initializing the class?

Comment: It is still an int. Thank you for taking the time to answer the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`param.Integer` inherits a `__get__` method from `param.Number`, which makes it a descriptor. That means when an instance is accessed as either a class or instance attribute, you don't get the `Integer` instance itself; instead, you get the result of its `__get__` method.

That is, `BaseClass.num_int` evaluates to `BaseClass.__dict__['num_int'].__get__(None, BaseClass)`, which returns some `int` value (possibly the default value?).

Comment: That is probably it. Thank you.